# Backbone Marionette events, Zurb Foundation's Reveal Modals

Tags: backbone.js, zurb-foundation, marionette

I'm building a modal popup by jamming a Backbone Marionette itemview into a Foundation Reveal modal. The modals appear but no events fire. Specifically, I'm trying to catch a click event.

I load Foundation from a Marionette Layout view.

```
   'use strict';

    define([
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'backbone',
        'region/actionbar',
        'region/modal',
        'text!/js/template/global.ejs',
        'js/views/actionbar/actionbar.js',
        'less!/style/global.less',
        'css!/js/bower_components/foundation/css/foundation.css',
        '/js/bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.js',
        '/js/bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js',
        'marionette'
    ], function ($, _, Backbone, ActionBar, Modal, Template, ActionBarView) {

        var GlobalLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
            template: _.template(Template),

            el: 'body',

            regions: {
                content: "#content",
                actionBar: ActionBar,
                modal: '#modal'
            },

            initialize: function(){
            },

            onRender: function(){
                // Load foundation
                $(document).foundation();
            },

            title: function(title) {
                // this.actionbar.title(title);
                // document.title = "Workbench :: " + title;
            }
        });

        var layout = new GlobalLayout();
        layout.render();


        return layout;
    });
```

The popup is being loaded from a click event in a view in the actionbar region. Here's the `Region`:

```
'use strict';

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'marionette'
], function ($, _, Backbone) {

    var ActionBar = Backbone.Marionette.Region.extend({
        el: "#action-bar"

    });

    return ActionBar;

});
```

...and here's the View in that region. `onSignUp()` jams my SignUp modal into the Modal region. It then re-initializes foundation.

```
'use strict';

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'layout/global',
    '/js/views/modals/sign-up.js',
    '/js/views/modals/sign-in.js',
    'model/user',
    'text!/js/template/actionbar/actionbar.ejs',
    'less!/style/global.less',
    'marionette'
], function ($, _, Backbone, layout, SignUp_Modal, SignIn_Modal, User, Template) {

    var ActionBarView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        initialize: function(){
            this.setElement('#action-bar');
        },

        template: _.template(Template),

        events: {
            "click .sign-in" : "onSignIn",
            "click .sign-up" : "onSignUp"
        },

        onSignUp: function(e){
            // e.preventDefault();

            layout.modal.show( new SignUp_Modal() );
            $(document).foundation();

        },

        onSignIn: function(e){
            // Prevent the link from doing anything.
            e.preventDefault();

            // Load modal popup that requests user to sign in     
            layout.modal.show( new SignIn_Modal() );
            $(document).foundation();
        }

    });

    return ActionBarView;
});
```

Finally, here's my SignUp_Modal view and its template.

'use strict';

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'model/user',
    'text!/js/template/modals/sign-up.ejs',
    'marionette'
], function ( $, _, User, Template){
    var Modal = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        events: {
            'click #join': 'onJoin',
            'click .me': 'onJoin'
        },

        template: _.template(Template),

        onJoin: function(e){
            // Check whether the click events do anything
            console.log('Heard it');
        }

    });

    return Modal;
});
```

Template:

```
<div id="signUp" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
  <form>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-8">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="small-3 columns">
              <label for="email" class="right inline">Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="small-9 columns">
              <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="small-3 columns">
              <label for="phone" class="right inline">Phone</label>
            </div>
            <div class="small-9 columns">
              <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="small-3 columns">
              <label for="pass" class="right inline">Password</label>
            </div>
            <div class="small-9 columns">
              <input type="password" id="pass">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <label>Username will be...</label>
              <input type="radio" name="username" value="email" id="username_email" checked><label for="username_email">Email</label>
              <input type="radio" name="username" value="phone" id="username_phone"><label for="username_phone">Phone</label>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="small-3 columns">
              <a href="#" class="button postfix" id="join">Join</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </form>
          <div class="me">blaaaa</div>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

I'm betting any of these would be helpful:

- Boilerplate example showing how to implement Zurb Foundation with a backbone project, specifically where you're jamming a backbone view into a foundation modal?
- Any general reasons why views don't hear click events?
- Have I improperly loaded the view into the region?

The error occurs specifically when I click either the element with class="me" or id="join". Both of these should call onJoin() but neither do.

Answer (score 2):

The events are not being trigger because foundation creates a new DOM element to hold the modal, this element is outside of your ItemView's instance's `el`, and as you might know Backbone only delegate events to the element associated with the view.

Comment: How do you fix this?